# How to set time from time picker dialog?

Tags: java, android, android-timepicker

I want to set two times i.e alert time and due Time. I have created two dialogs for alert time and due time. I tried to set both the times in different date objects. Still when I change alert time the due time also gets changed. I want to save both values differently.

```
    private int ALERT_TIME_DIALOG, ALERT_DATE_DIALOG,DUE_TIME_DIALOG,DUE_DATE_DIALOG;
      @Override
        public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout view, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second) {
            String hourString = hourOfDay < 10 ? "0"+hourOfDay : ""+hourOfDay;
            String minuteString = minute < 10 ? "0"+minute : ""+minute;
            String secondString = second < 10 ? "0"+second : ""+second;
            String aTime,dTime;
            SimpleDateFormat  df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

            if(ALERT_TIME_DIALOG == 2) {
                Date alertDate = new Date();
                mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                mCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
                alertDate = mCalendar.getTime();
                aTime = df.format(alertDate);
                alertTime.setText(aTime);
            }

            if(DUE_TIME_DIALOG  == 4){
                Date dueDate = new Date();
                mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                mCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
                dueDate = mCalendar.getTime();
                dTime = df.format(dueDate);
                dueTime.setText(dTime);
            }
        }


     alertTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    ALERT_TIME_DIALOG = 2;

                    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

                    TimePickerDialog tpd = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
                            AddTaskActivity.this,
                            now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                            now.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                            mHoursMode
                    );

                    tpd.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                            Log.d("TimePicker", "Dialog was cancelled");
                        }
                    });
                    tpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Timepickerdialog");
                }
            });


     dueTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    DUE_TIME_DIALOG = 4;

                    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

                    TimePickerDialog tpd = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
                            AddTaskActivity.this,
                            now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                            now.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                            mHoursMode
                    );

                    tpd.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                            Log.d("TimePicker", "Dialog was cancelled");
                        }
                    });
                    tpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Timepickerdialog");
                }
            });
```

What's wrong here.?
Thank u..

Comment: You should use only one flag to check which time you want to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify Your code as Below: You have Set two different tag for both Alert and Due date dialog. SO when you repeat the process both the value is set and in `onTimeSet` method both if statement get executed.

```
private int TIME_PICKER_DIALOG_TAG;
@Override
public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout view, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second) {
    String hourString = hourOfDay < 10 ? "0"+hourOfDay : ""+hourOfDay;
    String minuteString = minute < 10 ? "0"+minute : ""+minute;
    String secondString = second < 10 ? "0"+second : ""+second;

    SimpleDateFormat  df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

    Date date = mCalendar.getTime();
    if(TIME_PICKER_DIALOG_TAG == 2) {
        alertTime.setText(df.format(date));
    }else if(TIME_PICKER_DIALOG_TAG  == 4){
        dueTime.setText(df.format(date));
    }
}


alertTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        TIME_PICKER_DIALOG_TAG = 2;

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

        TimePickerDialog tpd = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
            AddTaskActivity.this,
            now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            now.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
            mHoursMode
        );

        tpd.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            Log.d("TimePicker", "Dialog was cancelled");
        }
        });
        tpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Timepickerdialog");
    }
});


dueTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        TIME_PICKER_DIALOG_TAG = 4;

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

        TimePickerDialog tpd = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
            AddTaskActivity.this,
            now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            now.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
            mHoursMode
        );

        tpd.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            Log.d("TimePicker", "Dialog was cancelled");
        }
        });
        tpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Timepickerdialog");
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried this way. Still it only changes the time of alert time. I Think I am initializing flag on click listener so its getting execute again.. How can I have both times?DhavalPatel